# Schedule Powershell script to run every hour

Tags: windows, powershell, taskscheduler

Please check this picture as following
[image]

I was looking at Window task scheduler to schedule my script to run each hour. The script will do some checks and will send an email .

I did not find options to schedule it for each 1 hour. I only found for every day, daily, weekly and so on.

Comment: scheduled task you don't need powershell for this. trigger -> repeat task every hour

Comment: I have one power shell script for some work and it will generate some report . So, I need the script to be executed per hour.

Comment: call it from scheduled task  eg  task would be to start PowerShell and run the specified script  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071496/run-a-powershell-script-in-the-background-once-per-minute

Comment: Yes. But it is not showing any option to run per hourly . I can find there for daily, weekly and other options . I just edited question with one link . Can you please check it once.

Comment: create the task  then -> new trigger -> daily -> repeat task every hour is one way of doing it. Or do it on commandline

Comment: Thanks. Got it under Advance Option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Task scheduler does show the option to configure hourly trigger as shown below.

[image: Trigger for a Task in Task Scheduler]

Another option you have is to run your PowerShell script as a Service and add the logic in your PowerShell script to trigger your main code once every hour.

**Refer:** [Video: Running PowerShell scripts as a real Windows Service!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CJXf4proZD8)
[How To Create a User-Defined Service](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/137890)

Answer (score 0):

Call it from scheduled task eg task would be to start PowerShell and run the specified script see [Run a powershell script in the background once per minute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071496/run-a-powershell-script-in-the-background-once-per-minute)

create the task then -> new trigger -> daily -> repeat task every hour is one way of doing it. Or do it on commandline